# Groovy regex match list from readlines()

Tags: regex, groovy, readlines

I am trying to read a text file and return all lines that do not begin with a #. In python I could easily use list comprehension list

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
     lines = [l.strip('\n') for l in f.readlines() if not re.search(r"^#", l)]
```

I would like to accomplish the same thing via Groovy. So far I have the below code, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
lines = new File("file.txt").readLines().findAll({x -> x ==~ /^#/ })
```

Comment: Does that not work?  You might need to change the findAll closure to `{ x -> !x.startsWith( '#' ) }`

Comment: tim_yates - `lines = new File(masterManifest).readLines().findAll({x -> !x.startsWith('#')})` works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In groovy, you generally have to use `collect` in place of list comprehensions.  For example:

```
new File("file.txt").readLines().findAll({x -> x ==~ /^#/ }).
    collect { it.replaceAll('\n', '') }
```

Note that `readLines()` already strips off newlines, so in this case it's not necessary.

For searching, you can also use the `grep()` method:

```
new File('file.txt').readLines().grep(~/^#.*/)
```